# Gulp: minify handlebars files before compiling

Tags: minify, handlebars.js, gulp

I see that at least gulp plugin `gulp-ember-handlebars` does not minifyes html. So I thought it would be nice to minify files before compiling. Something like this:

```
    gulp.src(paths.tmplInput)
    .pipe(minifyHTML({collapseWhitespace:true,removeComments:true}))
    .pipe(handlebars({outputType: 'browser'}))
    .pipe(concatStr('templates.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src'));
```

But then I noticed that `{{action}}` was removed too. That is not exactly what I want. Any solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48361324/209288 (if you are using html-minifier with the gulp wrapper)

you could set this option like:

```
.pipe(minifyHTML({ 
    collapseWhitespace:true, 
    removeComments:true, 
    ignoreCustomFragments: ["/{{[{]?(.*?)[}]?}}/"
  ]}
 ))
```